# Bounty statements that alter the original question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What should be done or is there a protocol to be inaugurated if someone offers a bounty on another’s question and the body seems to alter the question too much.

For example, this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48510/25495) has a bounty but the body of the bounty seems to alter the OP’s original question into something else.

How should we deal with this or should we just let it take it’s coarse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that explanation in the bounty was a completely different question and could be asked as a separate question:

something like

"Do any of the Church Fathers compare Mary or Eve to a deacon or deaconess?"

I think that's a perfectly valid question that would be well received.

Bounties like that should be flagged for removal since they definitely go against the spirit of the bounty system.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is just one of those things I dislike doing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything needs to be done. You can put whatever you want in the bounty description, but answers still need to answer the question. If someone asks for a different question in the bounty description then that's just them wasting their rep points.

Comment: I see where you are going but this bounty substantially altered the question to a point that the original question could not be answered if one wanted the bounty.